# How to convert an array into MySQL Table?

Tags: php, mysql, row

What I want to do is:

```
$array_data = array( "a" => array(1, 2, 3), "b" => array( 1, 2, 3 ) );

$table_converted = CONVERT_TO_MYSQL_TABLE( $array_data );

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $table_converted )) {
       echo $row['a'] . " union " . $row['b'];
}
```

Comment: What does that even mean? Why do you want to do that? Do you have a schema?

Comment: Then write a class that works with arrays?

Comment: I would suggest rewriting the class to work with arrays.  You'll spend less time working and more time doing.

Comment: Yeah Stephen, now works with arrays.. is the best way to do that... look, I did this question, because I want to get advantage of the MySQL Queries... with that data, is so crazy Idea... BYE!

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array, and construct an array with the same keys but in different order:

```
$array_data = array( "a" => array(1, 2, 3), "b" => array( 1, 2, 3 ) );

$results = array();
foreach ($array_data as $name => $values)
{
    foreach ($values as $i => $value)
    {
        $results[$i][$name] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($results);
```